# MSO_CONNECT not being detected. Getting number of lines on a slide?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I need to get the number of lines on a slide. To access the lines, I am using MSO_CONNECTOR as it is not an AUTO_SHAPE. However when I run the below it returns an None value for some reason. How can I know if a shape is a line or not? (tried using is_connector also returned an error)

```
def get_number_of_lines(slide):
    lines = 0
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if shape.shape_type == MSO_CONNECTOR:
           print('it is a line')
           lines = lines + 1 

    return lines
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, interesting. It looks like we left the `.shape_type` property off of the Connector object. I'll add an issue to get that fixed up.

In the meantime, you can check for a distinctive `Connector` property, like `.begin_x`:

```
def is_connector(shape):
    """Return True if `shape` is a connector (line), False otherwise."""
    return hasattr(shape, "begin_x")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like MSO_CONNECTOR's attribute should be used to compare.
for ex)

```
if shape.shape_type == MSO_CONNECTOR.STRAIGHT:
```

Comment: Same problem.. it doesn't catch it... I am adding manually lines in ppt and saving the file and then running the code above (including yours) and it doesn't catch any lines.. thanks

Comment: may need to iterate over the `Connector`s? https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html#connector-objects